# Source code of std:: namespace

Tags: c++, std

I want to use the `std::string` namespace + member, but I do not want the size of my file to increase by the size of the `#include <string>` file.

Is there anywhere that I can find the source code of the std:: namespace so I can just extract the string member and put it in my source so I don't get the increase in my binary size?

Please give me some suggestions, thank-you!

Comment: Well... the string-file is not that big, if I see it right there are the classes string, u16string, u32string and wstring and some global functions in this header file. (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)

Comment: `std::string` doesn't even live in `string.h`. The only portable way to get the definition of `std::string` is to `#include <string>`. You can find *the* sourcecode of `std::string` since there is more than one implementation of it. Not to mention the fact that including a header file won't cause an increase in binary size.

Comment: "...so I don't get the increase in my binary size." - You're *adding code*. If you're don't want that to increase your program size you're in for a big disappointment unless you plan to cut elsewhere. Have you actually determined how much *beyond acceptable* your code footprint with `<string>` included *and used*?   And fyi, `std::string` is in `<string>`, not `string.h`.  Regardless, my suggestion is use as-designed; don't use it if you can't afford it.

Comment: Did you try to compile with optimizations (e.g. `g++ -Os -Wall`)? Then the compiler is likely to remove any unneeded code. And you should use the standard `<string>` or else avoid `std::string`. BTW [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) is free software, so all the source code of standard libraries (which might use compiler magic thru builtins) is available and you could study it.

Comment: @Mankarse but using std::string will. So what I actually mean is, is there some similar alternative to std::string "that is more lighter on the calories"?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thank-you for your answer. That's exactly what I needed. I changed the optimization level in the file properties. I'm using the cl.exe compiler btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) on Linux (thru `g++`), it is free software and the source code of the standard library is available. So you could study its `<string>` header (some of which might perhaps use compiler magic like builtins or attributes).

Notice that if you `#include <string>` and ask the compiler to optimize (for size using `-Os`, or for speed using `-O2`) it is very likely that uneeded functions won't come in. At last, usually the `libstdc++` is dynamically linked (as a shared object) so does not consume space in every program (but is shared across several processes)

Comment: It was the -Os switch that I was looking for, but thanks for giving me the heads up on it!